# Refresh a page data in ionic app every x minutes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am making an application in which I need to refresh the data displayed on the page every 15 minutes. (without user action.. even if the user is currently viewing the page).

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I am trying to write a service that will raise events every 15 mins. and subscribing to the service in every page I need to refresh data in. But it seems its very cost intensive job. Would there be a better way to acheive this?

```
var timerID = setInterval(function() {
this.events.publish("timedEvent");
}, 60 * 1000 * 15); 

  events.subscribe('timedEvent', () => {
  this.getUserDetails();
});
```

Also i need to raise this event at every 15 min like (10:00 AM then 10:15 AM ....)

I this way to achieve this I need the timer to start exactly at 00:00. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Without the event, you can do it like this..

```
let timer = setInterval(()=> {
  this.getUserDetails();
  //you can stop the interval if you don't need it anymore
  clearInterval(timer)
}, 900000);
```

Since events are no longer supported, you should use [BehaviourSubjects()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)